# Factorizing a polynomial $f$ in $A[x]$ (with $A$ commutative), where $f$ has a zero in its field of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and $S$ a multiplicative subset of $A$ generated by $s\in A$ which is not a zero-divisor. Consider the polynomial ring $A[x]$.

> Given a polynomial $f\in A[x]$, suppose that $f(1/s)=0$ for $s\in S$. Does it follow by some application of the first isomorphism theorem that $f(x)=(sx-1)g(x)$, with $g(x)\in A[x]$?

On the one hand I *think* this can be proven by constructing an isomorphism from $A[x]$ modulo the relation $x=1/s$ (really the replacement of $x$ with $1/s$). This is evidently an isomorphism from $A[x]/(x=1/s)$ into $S^{-1}A$. It is tempting to conclude (though I'm not certain that this should work), that there must be some surjective homomorphism $\phi: A[X]\to S^{-1}A$ such that $\ker(\phi)=(sx-1)$. [Since generally $(A/B\cong A/C) \nRightarrow (B\cong C)$, it is not sufficient to conclude that, say, the kernel of $\psi: f\to f(1/s)$ is $(sx-1)$.]

I am especially interested in answers as to whether, say, $\psi$ has kernel $(sx-1)$. But for anyone who can follow my own attempt at a proof, I'm also interested in whether my argument breaks down or can be made to work rigorously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\, \phi\,$ kills $\rm\,f\,$ and $\rm\,sx\!-\!1\,$  so it kills the polynomial obtained by eliminating their constant terms, viz. $\rm\ f + (sx\!-\!1)\, f_0 =: x\, g \in ker\ \phi\ \Rightarrow\ g\in ker\ \phi\,,\,$ since $\rm\,s\,$ is not a zero-divisor. $\,$  Hence we deduce by induction on degree that $\rm\, sx\!-\!1\mid g\,$ thus $\rm\, sx\!-\!1\mid f\, =\, x\, g-(sx\!-\!1)\, f_0.\ \ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $ This method avoids the messy coefficient recursions in other approaches. It is worth stressing that this can be [deduced more conceptually](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3029243/242) from more general results. First, using the same obvious inductive proof as for the high-school polynomial division algorithm, we deduce that we can divide with remainder by any *monic* polynomial over any ring. In particular, since $\rm\,f(1/s) = 0\,$ we deduce by the Remainder Theorem that $\rm\ x\!-\!1/s\,\mid f(x)\ $ in  $\rm\, A[1/s][x]\, $ so $\rm\,f(x) = (x\!-\!1/s)\ g(x)/s^j\,$ for some $\rm\,g\in A[x].\,$ Thus $\rm\,s^{\,j+1}\ f(x) = (s\,x\!-\!1)\ g(x)\,$ so, by Euclid's lemma, $\rm\ sx\!-\!1\mid f(x)\,$ in $\rm\,A[x]\,$ since $\rm\,s\,$ is coprime to $\rm\,sx\!-\!1\,$ by $\rm\,(s,sx\!-\!1) = (s,1) = 1\, $ (explicitly, if $\rm\, sx\!-\!1\mid s\,f\ $ then it also divides $\rm\ x(sf) - (sx\!-\!1)f = f).$

More generally, monic division in $\rm A[1/s][x]$ yields a *nonmonic* division algorithm pulled back to $\rm\,A[x],\,$ namely if the divisor $\rm\,g\,$ has leading coefficient $\rm\,s\,$ then we obtain the following $\rm\,s\rm{-Division}$ Algorithm: $\rm\ s^{n} f = q\, g + r\ $ for some $\rm\,q,r\ \in A[x],\ n\in \mathbb N\ $ with $\rm\ deg\ r < deg\ g.$ This has an [elementary direct inductive proof,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) but it is less conceptual than said pullback from $\rm\,A[1/s].$

Comment: This is even more elegant. Thank you for the answer. This is my favorite, but I don't know the math.stackexchange ethics for changing the answer.

Comment: @Jay SE says to accept the answer most helpful to you. Changing accepted answers is encouraged if a more helpful answer later appears. This is not considered rude, e.g. see [here](http://bit.ly/n17mc6) and [here](http://bit.ly/uNJ5yx). In fact, not too infrequently you'll see folks encouraging the OP to deselect their answer in favor of a later appearing answer they consider better. My personal view is a bit more global: accept the answer that will be most helpful to students at your level (but not too quickly, so all have time to answer).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the links to the discussion regarding SE ethics on this.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3685341/242).

Answer (score 4):

By the the universal property of the polynomial ring there exists  an $A$-algebra morphism $\Phi :  A[x]\to S^{-1}A$ sending $x$ to $1/s$ .
Since  $\Phi$  vanishes on the ideal $(sx-1)$,  it induces a morphism $\phi:  A[x]/(sx-1)\to S^{-1}A $ which is clearly surjective.
 Let' s show $\phi$ is injective by proving that the kernel of $\Phi$ is $(sx-1)$ .

If  $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+...+a_nx^n$ satisfies $\Phi (p)=0$ , we have $a_0+a_1\frac{1}{s}+...+a_n (\frac{1}{s})^n=0$ or
 $\frac{1}{s^n} .( a_0s^n+...+a_n)=0 $
Since $A$ is a domain, this is equivalent to
      $$ a_0s^n+...+a_n=0  \quad (*) $$

To find a polynomial $q(x)=b_0+b_1x+...+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}$  such that  $p(x)=(sx-1).q(x)$ , it suffices to solve the system :

$$ b_i=-a_0s^{i-1}-a_1 s^{i-2}- ...- a_i=0 \quad (0\leq i\leq n-1) \quad  (**)      $$

$$  b_{n-1}s=a_n         \quad  (***)$$

The solution of $(*)$ is  $b_i=-a_0s^i -a_1 s^{i-1}-... -a_i$ and it satisfies $(***)$ thanks to $(*)$.

**Conclusion**
 We have proved that $\phi:  A[x]/(sx-1)\to S^{-1}A $ is an isomorphism of rings.
 (Actually this holds also if  $A$ has zero divisors,  by a small modification of the above reasoning )

Comment: Would verifying that $A[x]/(sx - 1)$ has the universal property of $A_s$ be shorter? Anyway, I think viewing $A[x]/(sx - 1)$ and $A_s$ (the usual pair construction) as being the same is important, so I like this.

Answer (score 2):

The homomorphism $\phi: A[X]\rightarrow S^{-1}A,\; X\mapsto \frac{1}{s}$ is surjective, since the elements of $S^{-1}A$ have the form $\frac{a}{s^k} = \phi (aX^k)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $a\in A$.

The kernel of $\phi$ is generated by $(sX-1)$: let $f$ be an element of the kernel; in $S^{-1}A$ it has the unit $\frac{1}{s}$ as a root. Now in general the following holds:

Let $f\in B[X]$ be a polynomial with coefficients in the commutative ring $B$ and such that $f(u)=0$, where $u\in B$ is a unit. Then $f=(X-u)g$ with $g\in B[X]$.

The proof follows easily by looking at the relation between the coefficients $a_k$ of $f$ and $b_k$ of $g$: $a_{k+1}=b_k-ub_{k+1}$.

Hence we get a factorization of the form $f=(X-\frac{1}{s})g$, $g\in S^{-1}A$. Looking again at the relation $a_{k+1}=b_k-ub_{k+1}$ and taking into account that $u=\frac{1}{s}$ it turns out that every $b_k$ has the form $sc_k$ for some $c_k\in A$, which proves the assertion.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer. I wish I could have chosen both answers. I chose this one because I think it is a bit more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Is the suggested idea of the universal property the following?

Since $s$ is a unit in $B$  (because $Xs\equiv 1$ in $B$), the homomorphism $\psi':A\to B$ such that $\psi'(s)=\frac 1s=X$ sends  $S=\{s^n\}$ into the units of $B$ so factors through $\pi:A\to S^{-1}A,\;a\mapsto \frac a1$ and induces a unique homomorphism $\psi: S^{-1}A\to B$ with $\psi(\frac a{s^n})=aX^n$ which is surjective.

Then copying the argument above, the surjection $\phi':\;A[X]\to S^{-1}A, \;f(X)\mapsto (\frac 1s)$ factors through the ideal $(sX-1)\subset \ker \phi'$ so there exists a surjection $\phi:B\to S^{-1}A$  defined by $aX^n\mapsto \frac a{s^n}$ with $B=A[X]/(sX-1)$.

Finally, $\phi$ and $\psi$  are inverse each other.