# The natural map $R\mapsto R[t]/(ft-1)$ is injective

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f\in R$ such that $f$ is not a zero divisor (thanks Darij for correction). How can I rigorously show that

> The canonical map $R\mapsto R[t]/(ft-1)$ is injective.

**Context:** This step shows up in Rabinowitch trick (when proving Nullstellensatz) where $R=k[x_1, x_2, …, x_n]$.

Comment: Surely not true, say, for $f = 0$. You need to require that $f$ is not a zero-divisor.

Comment: Hint: $R\left[t\right] / \left(ft-1\right)$ is isomorphic to the localization $f^{\star} R$, where $f^{\star}$ is the multiplicative system $\left\{1,f,f^2,f^3,\ldots\right\}$.

Comment: @darij Ah makes sense! So this really follows from the fact that the natural map $R\to S^{-1}R$ is injective if $S$ has no zero divisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element $a$ belongs to the kernel of the canonical morphism if and only if $a=(ft-1)P(t)$, where $P(t)\in R[t]$. Suppose $a\ne0$ and $P(t)=r_0+r_1t+\dots+r_nt^n$ exists, with $r_n\ne0$. Then
$$
(ft-1)P(t)=
-r_0+(fr_0-r_1)t+(fr_1-r_2)t^2+\dots+(fr_{n-1}-r_n)t^n+fr_nt^{n+1}
$$
so
\begin{align}
r_0&=-a\\
r_1&=-fa\\
r_2&=-f^2a\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
r_n&=-f^na\\
0&=f^{n+1}a
\end{align}
If $f$ is not a zero divisor, we have a contradiction.

Note that if $f$ is a zero divisor, the statement is false: if $fb=0$, then taking $P(t)=-b$, we have
$$
(ft-1)(-b)=fbt+b=b
$$
so $b$ belongs to the ideal generated by $ft-1$.

Comment: See my answer for a simpler way to present the proof.

Comment: Thanks both to you and Bill for your answers. The explicit computation done here was very helpful.

Comment: @Prism But there is no need for that (unenlightening) explicit computation. That's the point of my answer!

Comment: @BillDubuque: Yes, there is no need, per se. And that does make your answer shorter! I like this approach because expanding that quantity and equating coefficients is the first thing that would come to my mind, so it feels a bit more natural. Your approach is slicker but slightly harder to think of. Just my personal observations :)

Comment: @BillDubuque Unenlightening? It explicitly shows what $P$ is, which is probably the reason why Rotman used it. Tricks like yours are slick, but as enlightening as my direct proof. If you want to play “who's got the shortest proof”, then I can agree.

Comment: @egreg There's no need to explicitly compute $P(t)$ or my $g(t).\,$ But if one desires to do so then that is also clearer when done my way, $ $  i.e. $\,g (t) = (1\!+\!ft\!+\cdots+\!(ft)^n)r\,$ arises clearly by simply scaling the equation $\ r = (1\!-\!ft)g(t)\ $ by $\ (1\!+\!ft\!+\cdots+(ft)^n)\, =\, \dfrac{1\!-\!(ft)^{n+1}\!\!\!\!}{1- ft\quad }$ $\qquad$

Answer (score 2):

If $\,r\in R\,$ lies in the kernel, then $\,r = (1-ft)\,g\,$ for some $\,g\in R[t],\, \deg g =: n.\,$ Then

$$\begin{eqnarray}    r &=&  (1-ft)\,g &\Rightarrow&\   g(0) = r\qquad\ \, {\rm via\ \  coef}\ t^0 \\[.2em]
 \Rightarrow\  (1\!+\!ft\!+\dots+\!(ft)^n)\, r &=&  (\color{#c00}{1\!-\!(ft)^{n+1}})\, g &\Rightarrow&\   g(0)\,f^{n+1}\! = 0\ \ {\rm via\ \  coef}\ t^{n+1} \\[.2em]
& & &\Rightarrow&\ \ \ \ {\color{#0a0}{r\ f^{n+1} = 0}}\\[-1em]
\!\!\text{by scaling by}\,\  1\!+\!ft\!+\dots+\!(ft)^n \,\  &\!\!=&  \dfrac{\color{#c00}{1\!-\!(ft)^{n+1}}}{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!1-ft}
\end{eqnarray}$$

$\color{#0a0}{\rm Therefore}\,$ if $\,\color{#0a0}f\,$ is not a zero-divisor then $\,\color{#0a0}{r = 0}\,$ and the map is injective. $\ $ **QED**

**Remark** $\ $  This is used in the computation of the kernel of localization maps. As I [mentioned here,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162037/242) this simple proof seems to have been missed by most authors (e.g. Rotmans' *Advanced Modern Algebra* and all others I've seen give a proof like that in egreg's answer).

**Edit** $ $ Since the point of this approach seems to not be clear to some readers (cf. comments and downvotes), I will emphasize it explicitly. We do not use any recursion or telescopy above. Rather, we simply invoke the well-known identity $\,(1−x)(1+\cdots +x^n)=1−x^{n+1}\,$ for $\,x=ft.\,$ A common proof in many textbooks (and egreg's answer) amounts to *repeating* a telescopic proof of this identity in the proof at hand, vs. invoking it as a lemma as we do above (i.e. calling it by value vs. name in CS language). Inlining the proof (vs abstracting it out) only serves to complicate matters. Of course instances of the [Factor Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738715/242) (like the identity above) are ubiquitous in ring theory. We should strive to exploit this by appropriately abstracting out their application, esp. in instances like this where this structure is slightly hidden so it may not be immediately clear.

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88915/242) for motivational conceptual background.

Comment: The proof that egreg gives is the same as you do. In fact the telescoping is made explicit in his answer. The remark seems superfluous.

Comment: @Pedro The point is that the (standard) proof is much simpler to comprehend when presented like the above. There is no need for that explicit computation.

Comment: Well, that's simply subjective.

Comment: I think both presentations are of value :) So thanks for your contribution!

Comment: @Pedro Of course it goes without saying that judgements of simplicity are subjective. But I don't recall anyone who hasn't preferred this form when I showed it to them (including Cohn, Kaplansky, Rota, and many others that I've long forgotten).

Comment: In any case, one of the motivations for my interest in this and related topics is that I have long been interested in the historical development of these matters, esp, in the strange bias against the more natural, universal presentation-based construction of localizations or fraction fields (see the linked answer).

Comment: @All To clarify, I do *not* (explicitly) use any telescopy above. Rather, I use the well-known identity$\,(1\!-\!x)(1+x+\cdots+x^n) = 1-x^{n+1}\,$ for $\,x = ft.\,$ The common proof in egreg's answer amounts to *repeating* a telescopic proof of this identity into the proof at hand, vs. invoking it as a lemma as I do  (i.e. calling it by value vs. name in CS language). Inlining the proof (vs abstracting it out) only serves to complicate matters.