# Show that a ring of fractions and a quotient ring are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For a commutative ring $R$ with $1\neq 0$ and a nonzerodivisor $r \in R$, let $S$ be the set 
$S=\{r^n\mid n\in \mathbb{Z}, n\geq 0\}$ and denote $S^{-1}R=R\left[\frac{1}{r}\right]$.
 Prove that there is a ring isomorphism $$R\left[\frac{1}{r}\right]\cong \frac{R[x]}{(rx -1)}.$$

I'm thinking maybe I can find a homomorphism from $R[x]$ to $R\left[\frac{1}{r}\right]$ that has kernel $(rx-1)$, and then use the first isomorphism theorem. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yes, evaluation homomorphism can do the trick $\phi(p(x))=p\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)$.

Comment: Please search the site before asking a new question. This has been asked many, many times before: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152236/localisation-is-isomorphic-to-a-quotient-of-polynomial-ring), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765382/kx-y-xy-1-isomorphic-to-kx-frac1x/1765426#1765426), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/767765/localisation-isomorphic-to-a-quotient-of-polynomial-ring), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839555/s-1a-cong-ax-1-ax?rq=1) to name a few.

Comment: I reoponed this because the [prior linked dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152236/localisation-is-isomorphic-to-a-quotient-of-polynomial-ring) only handles the simpler domain case, but this question concerns the case of a general commutative ring.

Answer (score 4):

Tricky is proving the kernel $K = (rx\!-\!1).\,$ A simple way: if $f\in K$ then by [nonmonic division](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242)

$$ r^n f(x) = (rx\!-\!1)\,q(x) + r',\ \ {\rm for} \ \ r'\in R,\ n\in \Bbb N$$

Evaluating at $\, x = 1/r\,$ shows $\,r'\! = 0\,$ so $\,rx\!-\!1\mid r^n f\,\Rightarrow\,rx\!-\!1\mid f,\,$ by $\,(rx\!-\!1,r) = (1);\,$ more explicitly $\,rx\!-\!1\mid rg\,\Rightarrow\, rx\!-\!1\mid g = x(rg)-(rx\!-\!1)g$.

**Remark** $\ $ See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88915/242) for another proof and further discussion. If you already know basic (universal) properties of localizations then see the linked dupe for ways to employ them.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that $\frac{1}{r}$ has the property $\frac{1}{r}\cdot r=1$. That is, $\frac{1}{r}$ is not just an indeterminate object like $x$. Conceptually, this isomorphism should be easy to construct. Send $s\in R$ to itself for all $s$. Send $x\mapsto \frac{1}{r}$. This is clearly a surjective homomorphism 
$$ R[x]\xrightarrow{\phi} S^{-1}R.$$
Calculate $\ker\phi$. You will see that it is $(rx-1)$. Conclude using the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Why is the map clearly a surjection?

Comment: Let $a\in R$ and $r^k\in S$. Is it surjective because $\phi(ax^k) = \frac{a}{r^k}$, and the latter term is a general term of the ring of fractions?

Comment: Yes that is one way to see it.

Comment: It's clear that $(rx-1) \subseteq \ker(\phi)$, but how would I show that $\ker(\phi) \subseteq (rx-1)$? If I could use the division algorithm I could see how, but I can't see how to do it without the division algorithm.

Comment: @Wesley One simple way is to use the *nonmonic* division algorithm - see my answer.