# If $R$ is a UFD, $p(x)\in R[x]$ and $a/b$ is a root of $p(x)$ in the fraction field, then we have $p(x)=(bx-a)q(x)$ for $q(x)\in R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, divisibility

Suppose $R$ is a UFD and $p(x)\in R[x]$ a polynomial of degree $\ge 1$.  Suppose $\frac ab$ is in  the fraction field $K$ of $R$, with $a$ and $b\in R$ and $\text{gcd}(a,b)=1$, and such it is a root of $p(x)$, so $p(\frac ab)=0$.

**Question:** Is it true that then we have $p(x)=(bx-a)q(x)$ with $q(x)\in R[x]$?

It is clear that $q(x)\in K[X]$ exists and it is unique. Since the highest degree coefficient of $p(X)$ is divisible by $b$ and the constant term is divisible by $a$ (e.g. [the rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) ) one can easily show that the highest degree coefficient and the constant term of $q(x)$ are in $R$. This shows the case $p(x)$ has degree 2.

A suspect it should a consequence of the so called [Gauss Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)), but I was not able to find a convincing argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: $\,p(x) = (bx\!-\!a)q(x) = (bx-a)\frac{c}d\bar q(x)\,$ by Factor Theorem in $K[x],\,$   $\color{#0a0}{{\rm primitive} \ \bar q}\in R[x]$

thus $\, d p(x) = (bx\!-\!a)\, c\,\color{#0a0}{\bar q(x)},\,$ so taking $C = $ content of this

$\Rightarrow\,  d\,C(p(x))\  =\  1\cdot c\cdot\color{#0a0} 1,\, $ i.e. $\,d\mid c\,$ in $\,R,\,$ so $\,q = \frac{c}d \bar q\in R[x].\ \ $  **QED**

---

**Or** by [nonmonic Division:](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/116037/242) $\, b^k p(x) = (bx\!-\!a) q(x) + r,\ r\in R,\,$ so $\,r = 0\,$ by eval at $\,x = a/b.\,$ Note $\color{#c00}{(b,bx\!-\!a)}=\color{#0a0}{(b,a)}=\color{#c00}1,\,$ so $\,\color{#c00}{b\mid (bx\!-\!a)}q(x)\,\overset{\rm Euclid}\Longrightarrow\,b\mid q(x),\,$ thus $\,b^k\mid q(x)\,$ by induction [**or** we can use localization or the AC method as described in the link]. This proof works not only when $R$ is a gcd domain, but also when the *ideal* $\,\color{#0a0}{(b,a)}=(1)\,$ in any commutative ring $R.\,$ See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/88915/242).

Comment: The "nonmonic division" answer is the best because it makes clear that this only depends on the root $a/b$ in question having a gcd between $a$ and $b$; the answer *does not* depend on any global property of $R$.

Comment: @Badam Indeed, that was part of my motivation for adding that method even though the OP leaned towards Gauss. A warm welcome back to you.

Comment: Thank you Bill, I appreciate that! Warm regards to you as well.  As for the comment, I only meant it as an endorsement of your answer, which I feel is the pedagogically 'right' one.

Answer (score 1):

By the Factor Theorem, since $f(a/b)=0$, we have
$$f(x)=\left(x-{\small{\frac{a}{b}}}\right)v(x)$$
for some $v\in K[x]$.

Letting $g(x)=v(x)/b$, we have 
$$f(x)=(bx-a)g(x)$$
where $g\in K[x]$.

Our goal is to show $g\in R[x]$.

Letting $d\in R$ be the least common multiple of the denominators of the fractionally reduced coefficients of $g$, it follows that 
$$g(x)=G(x)/d$$
where $G\in R[x]$ is primitive.

Then from $f(x)=(bx-a)g(x)$, we get $d{\,\cdot}f(x)=(bx-a)G(x)$.

By Gauss' lemma, since $bx-a$ and $G$ are primitive in $R[x]$, the product $(bx-a)G(x)$ is primitive in $R[x]$.

Hence $d{\,\cdot}f(x)$ is primitive in $R[x]$, so $d$ is a unit of $R$.

Finally, since $G\in R[x]$ and $d$ is a unit of $R$, the equation $g(x)=G(x)/d$ implies $g\in R[x]$, as was to be shown.